# MySql sum DISTINCT after join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table that join together  ( Orders and Order_item)
When I use join I get duplicates  records then I eliminate them with `DISTINCT`, but when I want  to get sum the  the `shipping_price` `DISTINCT` not works because  it just eliminate the same price  value and I all my prices are same I get 1 not sum !

If I don't use `DISTINCT` , I get rows per each items in order

```
SELECT   sum(DISTINCT shipping_price) FROM `product_order`
INNER JOIN `product_address`
ON `product_order`.`address_id` = `product_address`.`id`
INNER JOIN `product_item`
ON `product_order`.`id` = `product_item`.`order_id`
WHERE (`status`<>2) 
AND (`company_id`=1968)
AND DATE(date)='2021-08-31'
ORDER BY `product_order`.`id` DESC
```

how to get sum of shipping price correctly ..

data in `order_table` is

```
id     shipping_price    status 
       100
       200
       200
       100
```

sum = 600 , but how to get it, if I did't `DISTINCT`, I get more than one row per `order_items` row counts that join tho order..

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: `sum(distinct)` is never the right thing to use, unless you are demonstrating things in SQL that should never be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery instead of a join.

```
SELECT (
    select sum(shipping_price) 
    FROM product_item 
    WHERE po.`id` = `product_item`.`order_id` 
) as shipping_price
FROM `product_order` po
INNER JOIN `product_address`
ON `product_order`.`address_id` = `product_address`.`id`
WHERE (`status`<>2) 
AND (`company_id`=1968)
AND DATE(date)='2021-08-31'
ORDER BY `product_order`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you and I have a question  :

Comment: "( select sum(shipping_price+post_tax+pack_price)  FROM `product_order`  and DATE(date)='2021-08-31' ) AS `deductions`", this is my subquery , and how to pass date to this from above query, I make query group by date and want pass date to this subquery.

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquery to get your shipping prices.  Something like this:

```
    SELECT product_order.id, 
           SUM(product_item.price * product_item.quantity) shipping_price
      FROM product_order
      JOIN product_item ON product_order.id = product_item.order_id
     GROUP BY product_order.id
```

The trick here is to get a subquery that delivers *exactly one row per order*, with the summed-up shipping priced in it. Do your SUM() ... GROUP BY ...` in the subquery. That way you'll avoid any duplication of items.

TEST THIS before you proceed to make sure it works: giving each order id and its shipping price.

Then use it as if it were a table, JOINing it to the rest.

```sql
SELECT   total.shipping_price,
         product_order.id,
         product_address.*
   FROM  product_order
   JOIN  product_address 
           ON product_order.id = product_address.order_id
   JOIN  (
        SELECT product_order.id, 
               SUM(product_item.price * product_item.quantity) shipping_price
          FROM product_order
          JOIN product_item ON product_order.id = product_item.order_id
         GROUP BY product_order.id 
         ) total ON product_order.id = total.id
  ORDER BY product_order.id = total.id
```

Comment: Both answer are correct and I mark first answer , and thank you to you for details that share thank you very much <3

Comment: and ( select sum(shipping_price+post_tax+pack_price) FROM product_order and DATE(date)='2021-08-31' ) AS deductions", this is my subquery , and how to pass date to this from above query, I make query group by date and want pass date to this subquery.

Comment: Please ask another question rather than asking a followup question in a comment.